# Is Adi Shankaras sub-commentary (Vivarana) on Vyasa's Patanjali Yoga sutras commentary available online or as PDF book?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya, yoga-sutras

It is believed that Adi Shankara has also written a sub commentary on Yoga sutras of Patanjali.

This is A previously unknown sub-commentary  recently discovered in around 1952 on the Vyasa commentary of  Yoga Sutras of Patanjali ascribed to Sri  Adi Shankaracharya.According to scholors , it is now increasingly   accepted as authentic .

One such book is [**Sankara on the Yoga Sutras**](https://sfvedanta.org/books/sankara-on-the-yoga-sutras/) - authored by Trevor Leggett.

---

My questions - Is Adi Shankaras sub-commentary  (Vivarana)  on Vyasa's Patanjali Yoga sutras commentary avaliable online or as  public domain  book  in PDF format with original sanskrit verses.?

Comment: do u mean Krishna Dvaipāyana by term Vyasa?

Comment: @YDS Yes , see this - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26333 and other answers related to Badarayana.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very interesting to know that Adi Shankaracharya would have written Bhashya on Yoga Sutras of Patanjali. The idea of Adi Shankaracharya's view on Patanjali Yoga Sutras often comes in my mind and the only thing known/available is that in his commentary on BrahmaSutras, Adi Shankaracharya refuted the Yoga School just by a single paragraph. (Actually BrahmaSutras debates with Samkhya considerably and when it comes to Yoga, it says since Samkhya is refuted, Yoga is also). This was one of the reason for asking the question: [Has Swami Vivekananda discussed regarding the refutation of Yoga Darshana in Vedanta Sutras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24576/277). The answer gives us an idea that the practice of Yoga and philosophy of Yoga can be different things and practice of Yoga would be accepted by Vedanta.

Coming back to the point of question, ***Yes!***, I've just found a scanned book [**Patanjala-Yogasutra-Bhasya Vivaranam of Sankara-Bhagavatpada**](https://archive.org/details/Patanjala-yogasutra-bhasyaVivaranamOfSankara-bhagavatpada) on Internet Archive. It's tagged under *opensource* collection.

Here is the detail of book:

> Rama Sastri & Krishnamurthi Sastri, S. R. (Eds.) Pātn̄jala[sic]-yogasūtra-bhāṣya Vivaraṇam of Śaṅkara-Bhagavatpāda Critically Edited with Introduction (*Madras: Government Oriental Manuscripts Library, 1952*), Madras Govt. Oriental Series no. 94.

Here is a sample image of the book:

> [image]

You can get it in [**PDF** format 64MB](https://archive.org/download/Patanjala-yogasutra-bhasyaVivaranamOfSankara-bhagavatpada/1952RamaAndKrishnamurthy_patanjalayogasutravbhasyavivarana_1952.pdf)

Note: The authenticity of the work is also discussed in preface.

---

As mentioned in the question  the english translation of Adi Shankara's sub-commentary  (Vivarana)  on Vyasa's Patanjali Yoga sutras   authored by Trevor Leggett is also available in [**English**](https://www.tlayt.org/sankara-on-the-yoga-sutras/)  on his Adhyatma Yoga Trust  Website which we can read over there.

Comment: Yes , a nice find. I have  updated the answer with the contents of the book "Sankara on the Yoga Sutras - authored by Trevor Leggett"  , which is in english. So  together with your Sanskrit book the circle is complete. :- )

Answer (score 0):

Sanskrit text of Shanakracharya's Vivaranam is available on archive.org - https://archive.org/details/Patanjala-yogasutra-bhasyaVivaranamOfSankara-bhagavatpada/page/n261/mode/2up

Sanskrit text with English translation is authored by T.S. Rukmani- 
https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/yogasutrabhasyavivarana-of-sankara-shankaracharya-2-vols-IDC109/